# working with $http.post function

Tags: angularjs

I want to save data using AngularJS and RestApi. I am sending an object in data parameter.

I tried both $http.post() direct method and $http() method , but non of these are working.
Always the error coming is "Method not allowed-405"

I am running on local machine.

**Edit:**

Eventually by doing some modifications like I specified "localhost:xxx" before the 'api/abc', now I am getting the error as "The requested resource does not support the http method 'POST'".

Comment: I saw your edit. My answer still addresses that. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @Tim Castelijns I didn't understand how to configure the http verbs on IIS. But I tried the same by creating different application and POST request is being generated. The only change I made was change the datatype of the variable that I want to pass. But I don't think I was the reason behind that error. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the API you're using does not support POST requests to the URL you're trying to POST to

More info from http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html below

> All Web servers can be configured to allow or disallow any method. For example if a Web server is 'read-only' (no client can modify URL resources on the Web server), then it could be set up to disallow the PUT and DELETE methods. Similarly if there is no user input (all the Web pages are static), then the POST method could be disallowed. So 405 errors can arise because the Web server is not configured to take data from the client at all.

Comment: But all other sites are running on my same machine.

Comment: You said it yourself, *other sites*. They may have different implementations regarding what kind of requests to allow etc.